# Can I configure python to have matlab like print?

Tags: python, matlab

Can I configure python to have matlab like print, so that when I just have a function

```
returnObject()
```

that it simply prints that object without me having to type print around it? I assume this is not easy, but something like if an object does not get bound by some other var it should get printed, so that this would work.

```
a = 5 #prints nothing
b = getObject() #prints nothing
a #prints 5
b #prints getObject()
getObject() #prints the object
```

Comment: I don't believe this is a possibility to do at the code level due to how the language is specifically built to recognize certain types of statements.

Comment: Have you tried IPython Terminal (not notebook)?

Comment: I think the Python debugger might do something like this. It isn't the answer you're after, but it might not be too far off

Comment: As mentioned below, I find ipython notebook very clunky. It is slow and laggy. I don't know if that is pycharms fault or ipythons, but I haven't found a good solution to the laggines yet. So I'm looking for something better.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an ipython notebook individual cells work like this. But you can only view one object per cell by typing the objects name. To see multiple objects you'd need to call print, or use lots of cells.

Comment: Hmm close but not really what I was looking for. I find the notebooks somehow clunky with all the setup needed. At least it's kinda slow in pycharm

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script to modify the original script based on a set of rules that define what to print, then run the modified script.

A basic script to do this would be:

```
f = open('main.py', 'r')
p = open('modified.py', 'w')

p.write('def main(): \n')

for line in f:
    temp = line
    if len(temp) == 1:
        temp = 'print(' + line + ')'

    p.write('\t' + temp)

p.close()

from modified import main

main()
```

The script main.py would then look like this:

```
x = 236
x
```

output:

```
236
```

Comment: And what about multiline docstrings which contain a single meaningless character?

Comment: Surely they woud be printed in matlab as well? You'd just need to set the rules up properly. e.g. could have lines finish with a semicolon to supress output if you want as well.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is as follows: parse AST of Python code, replace every expression with call to `print` and content of expression as argument and then run the modified version. I'm not sure whether it works with every code, but you might try. Save it as `matlab.py` and run your code as `python3 -m matlab file.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ast
import os
import sys

class PrintAdder(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def add_print(self, node):
        print_func = ast.Name("print", ast.Load())
        print_call = ast.Call(print_func, [node.value], [])
        print_statement = ast.Expr(print_call)
        return print_statement

    def visit_Expr(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.value, ast.Call) and node.value.func.id == 'print':
             return node
        return self.add_print(node)

def main():
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('infile', type=argparse.FileType(), nargs='?', default='-')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with args.infile as infile:
        code = infile.read()

    file_name = args.infile.name

    tree = ast.parse(code, file_name, 'exec')
    tree = PrintAdder().visit(tree)
    tree = ast.fix_missing_locations(tree)

    bytecode = compile(tree, file_name, 'exec')
    exec(bytecode)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Looks exactly like what I had in mind, will try it tomorrow.

Comment: @Hakaishin Also, this should be probably modified a little, if you use Python 2.